# C# wpf performing scale, translation transform using delta manipulation

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to perform scale and translation transform on ellipse and this is my code:

```
void ellipse_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
   {

       Ellipse rp = (Ellipse)sender;
       if (e.PinchManipulation != null)
       {
           ((CompositeTransform)rp.RenderTransform).ScaleX *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
           ((CompositeTransform)rp.RenderTransform).ScaleY *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;

       }

       ((CompositeTransform)rp.RenderTransform).TranslateX += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
       ((CompositeTransform)rp.RenderTransform).TranslateY += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
   }
```

Code works fine but the problem is, after performing scale transform, translation doesn't work perfectly, it either slows down or jumps, I think it happens because of the position of a center changes in pinch manipulation. How do I avoid that? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/12/21/wpf-manipulation-basics.aspx) of the sort of manipulation you're trying to do. Based on what I saw in that sample, your problem is that you're not setting the center point of your scale transform.

From the linked-to example/walkthrough:

```
Point center = new Point(this.BasicRect.RenderSize.Width / 2.0, this.BasicRect.RenderSize.Height / 2.0);
this.scale.CenterX = center.X;
this.scale.CenterY = center.Y;
this.scale.ScaleX *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
this.scale.ScaleY *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y;
```